# From $6$ different marbles $2$ are chosen

Tags: combinatorics

> From $6$ different marbles $2$ are chosen and between them the other balls are placed in a number (in a row). In how many ways we can arrange the marbles?

How to approach the problem? Is the count $6!=720$?

Answer (score 1):

Your questions is equivalent to the question : placing$ 6 $different balls in $6$ places..

Thus,you are totally right , it will be $$6!$$

Answer (score 0):

How about ${6\choose2}=15$ for the two marbles, times $4!=24$, for the remaining $4$.

Of course, that's $360$.  Then there are two ways to arrange the two, so we still get $720$.

Comment: Right.  So I'm still getting $720$. @NimuBasak